# MKR Wifi 1010 Project Design

Tags: system-design

I am newer to microcontrollers and have my first project I would like to try. I have started to sketch out a basic design and would like feedback on things that I may be missed or over looked. I understand I am new and things are probably not correct or I might miss use terminology, please feel free to correct me in any aspect.

Project Scope- I would like to integrate the MKR Wifi 1010 into Alexa using IoT to have an Alexa command sent to the MKR Wifi 1010 that then pulls in a relay that actuates a 12v solenoid.

Hardware

Power supply 1- FQCMOGU AL-1250, Input 100-240v 1.6a, Output 12v 5a
Power supply 2- Drok 15w DC/DC, Output 5v 3a
Microcontroller- Arduino MKR Wifi 1010
Relay- Songle SRD-05VDC-SL-C
Solenoid Valve- Beduan 12v

Here is a sketch of my original plan. Let me know any safeties/ protections I may have missed, calculations that do not make sense or if there is an easier/ better way. I have not order the hardware yet and want some people better at this than me to check it over before I do.

[image]

Comment: a common project with Arduino IoT Cloud and MKR 1010. https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/303628/arduino-iot-cloud-amazon-alexa-integration-4e6078

Comment: @Juraj Thank you for the response. I did read that article and it is the reason I chose the MKR 1010 for this project.

What I was looking for out of this question was a second opinion on my design to make sure I am not setting my self up for any early failures or better methods of achieving this project.

I will re-read the article to make sure I did not miss anything.